# Python Create new DataFrame by conditionally checking two separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm rather new to Python and Pandas as well. I would like to create a new data frame from conditionally checking two existing/separate Data frames. Both dataframes and the new one I intend to create have the same size and indexes.

The existing dataframes are an equivalent of this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['1', '2', '3', '4'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['1', '2', '3', '4'])

>>> df1
      1         2         3         4
0 -1.435173  0.230277  0.350859  0.200648
1  0.070976  0.827203 -0.874663 -0.382205
2 -1.991096  0.884184  0.992237 -1.289843
3 -1.615785 -1.737100 -0.646080 -0.782255
4  0.265713 -0.086915 -0.115174 -2.156504

>>> df2
      1         2         3         4
0 -1.504168 -0.613035 -0.145030  0.947341
1 -0.684728  2.281224  0.771786 -0.318042
2  1.374862  0.820146 -1.212940 -0.370513
3 -0.110245  2.548307  0.391108  0.069860
4 -0.631652 -0.329425 -0.282044 -0.229726
```

Now I want to create a new df3 based on these DataFrames. I already created an array with the same shape via:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(df1.shape), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
```

First I like to set the starting value of the first row (row = 0) based on a list:
`L = [7,5,2,3]`

My conditions to fill the remainder of df3 are:

> if df1 > 0 : df3 = previous value within that column - df1 value
>
> else:
>
> > if df2 >0 : df3 = value first row
> >
> > else: df3 = previous value within that column

Would be very happy with any advice on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the first row of `df3` using [`.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) and just assigning the list:

```
df3.loc[0] = L
```

I'm not totally sure how you want the rest to behave: when you reference the "previous value in each column" of `df3` do you mean the value before being transformed by `df1` and `df2` (0) or the value afterwards?  If the former, you can use `np.where` to perform your logical operations:

```
df3.loc[1:] = np.where(
    df1 > 0, 
    df3.shift() - df1, 
    np.where(
        df2 > 0, 
        df3.loc[0], 
        df3.shift()
    )
)[1:]
```

You can put it all on one line, but it's easier to see how it works like this.  Let's break that down a bit.  To begin, you use `.loc` again so that you're only assigning the rows of `df3` after the first one.  Then you're using `np.where`, which returns an array based on a conditional statement.

```
df3.loc[1:] = np.where(
```

The next line is your first conditional: cell locations where `df1` is positive.

```
    df1 > 0,
```

If it's positive, the array takes the value from the next line, which is the values of `df3` shifted down one row minus the value of `df1`.

```
    df3.shift() - df1,
```

If the value of a cell in `df1` isn't positive, you assign the value based on a second `np.where` conditional.  Here, the first test is whether the value of the cell in `df2` is positive, and if it is, you use the value from the first row of `df3`.  If not, you use `.shift()` again to use the previous row of df3.

```
    np.where(
        df2 > 0, 
        df3.loc[0], 
        df3.shift()
    )
```

Finally, you only take the rows of the returned array beyond the first one.

```
)[1:]
```

That should do it!  Let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works well for the first two rows but then the generated df3  is displaying incorrect results. For the remaining rows df3 displays (- df1) when df1 is positive. I suppose the issue is caused by incorrectly defining that the condition is relevant for the entire dataframe. Is the statement `df3.loc[1:]` sufficient to make it applicable to the whole remainder of the dataframe?

Comment: _"when you reference the "previous value in each column" of df3 do you mean the value before being transformed by df1 and df2 (0) or the value afterwards?"_ Ok, this is the reason why it is not displaying what I want df3 to look like. I want to reference the previous value after the transformation by df1 and df2.